# mongoose: send data back without saving

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, mongoose

I just started using **node**, **backbone** and **mongoose** not so long ago to create my first web app.

At the very beginning, I followed tutorials, and used backbone client side to define models. Those models mirror my mongoose schemas server side.

When I run [**schema.save()**](http://mongoosejs.com/) on one of my models, my data is automatically sent back to the client, with an **_id**.
But now that my app is almost finished, I realize that I don´t really need to save anything, as the only thing I do is query an api, and the data doesn´t have to be reused.

So my question is, **what is the best way to keep the same mechanisms, but without saving anything?**

The end reason is that I plan to run the app on an ec2 instance, and knowing that I don´t need to save anything, I think it is more beneficial to reduce the IO usage by not having any database.

Thanks, and sorry if the question seems dumb.

Comment: Are you using some form of REST interface to serve the models from mongoose? Also, I assume you mean client side save in backbone rather than server side? Why not just not call save on models if you dont want to save them -- Backbone.js doesn't persist by default.

Comment: Yes, I use a REST interface to communicate with the server. It sends a POST request with the info to save in the db. Server side, the info is used to grab more info using an api. The, I have to send the results back to the client. The mongoose save method currently helps me do that, but it also saves the stuff in the db, which I don´t want